# supA, infA, maxA, minA

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Having the set $$A=\{x: x \leq 0, x^2+x-1<0\}$$
I am asked to find $\sup A, \inf A, \max A, \min A$. I found the roots of the equation $x^2+x-1=0$, which are

$$\frac{-1+ \sqrt{5}}{2} \text{ and } \frac{-1- \sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

Since $x \leq 0$, we have $x \in \left( \frac{-1- \sqrt{5}}{2},0 \right]$. So

$$A= \left\{x:x  \in \left( \frac{-1- \sqrt{5}}{2},0 \right] \right\}.$$

So $\sup A=0, \max A=0, \inf A= \frac{-1- \sqrt{5}}{2}, \nexists \min A$. Is this correct?

Comment: That all seems correct to me. When you have proven that $A$ is the interval you give, I think the min, max, inf and sup are immediate.

Comment: @Ragnar Ok..Is there a way to prove that, or do I have to say just the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think proving them would just be writing out the definitions of them for this case. The maximum is trivial (so the supremum is trivial too). It has no minimum, because you can always find a smaller number in $A$ (proof by contradiction). The infimum might be the most complicated one, but you can easily see that it is less then every number larger than $\frac{-1-\sqrt 5}2$, for the same reason as the minimum. We see that $-\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ is smaller than all elements in $A$, and so it is the infimum.

Comment: Ok!!!Thanks a lot for your answer!!!